# Changing language on click of button: Android

Tags: android, localization

I am working on a project in which I have to change the locale on button click. I had set the  default locale as hindi. When the app first starts, the contents are shown in hindi. When I click on the button it will change to english. Now I want that when I again press the button the content shold change back to hindi. But this is not working. I van switch hindi to english  but not vice versa. Below I am posting my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button btn1;
TextView textView1;
String LOCALE_HINDI = "hi";
String LOCALE_ENGLISH = "en";
Locale mLocale;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_HINDI);
    Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = mLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(LOCALE_HINDI.equals(mLocale.toString()))
            {
                mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_ENGLISH);
                Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = mLocale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Log.d("LocaleTest", "if block");
            }//if
            else if (LOCALE_ENGLISH.equals(mLocale))
            {
                mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_HINDI);
                Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = mLocale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Log.d("LocaleTest", "else if block");
            }//else if
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: may be you should replce 
else if (LOCALE_ENGLISH.equals(mLocale))
with
else if (LOCALE_ENGLISH.equals(mLocale.toString()))

Comment: hello have solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Change `else if` block

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
   Button btn1;
   TextView textView1;
   String LOCALE_HINDI = "hi";
   String LOCALE_ENGLISH = "en";
   Locale mLocale;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_HINDI);
       Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
       Configuration config = new Configuration();
       config.locale = mLocale;
       getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
       getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
       this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
       textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

       btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
             if(LOCALE_HINDI.equals(mLocale.toString()))
             {
                  mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_ENGLISH);
                  Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
                  Configuration config = new Configuration();
                  config.locale = mLocale;
                  getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
                  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                  MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                  Log.d("LocaleTest", "if block");
               }//if
              else if (LOCALE_ENGLISH.equals(mLocale.toString()))
              {
                  mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_HINDI);
                  Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
                  Configuration config = new Configuration();
                  config.locale = mLocale;
                  getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
                  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                  MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                  Log.d("LocaleTest", "else if block");
               }//else if
          }
     });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me how should I check the condition?

Comment: just replace your else-if block with this code and check whether if its working or not

Comment: Did it as you said but still facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing is not the correct way. Every time when I called setContentView(), my previous view got invalidated. So, in order to buttons to work, again id of button will be required and onClickListener need to be set on button. And this will create a mess, block inside block and so on.

Answer (score -1):

try this methode :

```
  public String languageCheck() {
    String lCode="en";
    if(PersistData.getStringData(getApplicationContext(), "LNG").equalsIgnoreCase("en")) {
        lCode="hi";
    }
    else if(PersistData.getStringData(getApplicationContext(), "LNG").equalsIgnoreCase("hi")) {
        lCode="en";
    }
    return lCode;
}
```